# Do spaces admit a weak cogenerating set?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category. Say that a class of objects $\mathcal S \subseteq \mathcal C$ is *weakly cogenerating* if the functors $Hom_{\mathcal C}(-,S)$ are jointly conservative, for $S \in \mathcal S$. That is, a map $X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ is an isomorphism if and only if it induces bijections $Hom_C(Y,S) \to Hom_C(X,S)$ for every $S \in \mathcal S$.

Of course, every category $C$ admits a weakly cogenerating class -- namely, take $\mathcal S = \mathcal C$. But it's frequently important to have a cogenerating *set* -- i.e. to require that $\mathcal S$ is small.

**Question:** Does the homotopy category (of spaces) admit a weak cogenerating set?

It's clear that the homotopy category of simply-connected spaces admits a weak cogenerating set -- we can take $\mathcal S = \{K(\mathbb Z, n) \mid n \geq 2\}$ or alternatively $\mathcal S = \{K(k,n) \mid n \geq 2, k \in \{\mathbb Q, \mathbb F_p\}\}$ in this case by the cohomology Whitehead theorem. But I'm pessimistic about the chances of doing something similar with arbitrary spaces.

- Relatedly, I wonder whether the category of groups admits a weak cogenerating set.
- I also wonder whether the class of *truncated* spaces -- those spaces $S$ for which $\pi_k(S) = 0$ for $k$ sufficiently large -- is a cogenerating class for the homotopy category. What about the class of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces?

Comment: It amuses me that, in my native language, such a class of objects would be called *strongly* cogenerating.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Ah, but I _don't_ ask that $Hom_C(-,S)$ be jointly _faithful_, so a weakly cogenerating class in the above sense is not even cogenerating!

Comment: Good point! Indeed, after Kelly, in his book (where my usage comes from), defines a strong generator, he says "*In fact the above definition of a strong generator is far from ideal unless $\mathcal{B}_0$ admits finite limits; but we have chosen it for simplicity since this is usually the case in applications.*" Of course, this is not the case in your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any infinite set $X$ let $S_X$ be the group of bijections $\sigma \colon X\to X$ such that $\{x : \sigma(x)\neq x\}$ is finite.  This still has signature homomorphism, and the alternating subgroup $A_X$ is simple, and has the same cardinality as $X$.  Now let $\mathcal{G}$ be a set of groups, and put $\kappa = \max \{|G|:G\in\mathcal{G}\}$.  Then $\text{Hom}(A_X,G)$ will be a singleton for all $G\in\mathcal{G}$ and $X$ with $|X|>\kappa$ (because the kernel of any homomorphism is nontrivial by cardinality, and so is the whole of $A_X$ by simplicity).  So $\mathcal{G}$ is not a weak cogenerating set.

It doesn't seem to be straightforward to deduce the corresponding result for the homotopy category.

**EDIT** To summarize the discussion in the comments, we can indeed deduce the corresponding result for the homotopy category with a little more work. [Choose](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348640/do-there-exist-acyclic-simple-groups-of-arbitrarily-large-cardinality/348643#348643) an acyclic simple group $G$ bigger than the fundamental group of any space in $\mathcal S$. Then any map $f: BG \to S$ for $S \in \mathcal S$ is trivial on $\pi_1$ by simplicity, so it lifts to the universal cover $\tau_{\geq 2} S$. By acyclicity, the composite map $BG \to \tau_{\geq 2} S \to K(\pi_2(S),2)$ is trivial so $f$ lifts through the 2-connected cover $\tau_{\geq 3} S$. Continue in this manner, lifting through the Whitehead tower to see that $f$ is nullhomotopic. Thus $\mathcal S$ does not distinguish $BG$ from a point, and is not weakly cogenerating.

Comment: Can we adapt this to the homotopy category like this? Given a set $S$ of spaces, make a group $G$ bigger than all fundamental groups of all elements of $S$, such that $G$ is the fundamental group of an acyclic space. Now if $X\in S$ then every map $F\to X$ is homotopic to a constant because we can first lift to a universal cover using cardinality and then lift all the way up the Postnikov tower using acyclicity. So the map $F\to \ast$ induces a bijection $Hom(\ast,X)\to Hom(F,X)$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Yes, I think that works.  I don't remember the construction of large acyclic groups but I think it is in Kan-Thurston.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie Thanks, I'd accept this as an answer! To clarify, you claim there exist _simple_ groups $G$ of arbitrarily large cardinality such that $G = \pi_1(F)$ for an acyclic space $F$. Choosing such $F$ sufficiently large, and given $f: F \to X$ for $X \in \mathcal S$, we inductively find lifts $f_k: F \to \tau_{\geq k+1} X$ through the _Whitehead_ tower of $X$ since the composite map $F \xrightarrow{f_k} \tau_{\geq k} X \to K(\pi_k X, k)$ is null -- by simplicity when $k=1$ and by acyclicity from there on. So $f$ factors through the limit of the Whitehead tower, which is contractible.

Comment: Concerning the existence of such $G,F$, I think it's easy -- let $G$ be a sufficiently large simple group (e.g. the alternating group as in Neil's answer). Note that since $G$ is simple, its abelianization is trivial, i.e. $H_1(BG) = 0$. Start with $BG$ and then just keep gluing in cells of dimension 3 and higher to kill all the homology to obtain $F$. This doesn't affect the fundamental group.

Comment: You can't kill H_2 by attaching 3-cells if pi_2 is trivial. But I'm sure it's easy. If G is simple (and nonabelian) and H_2G is trivial then the homotopy fiber of $BG\to BG^+$ is acyclic and has $\pi_1=G$.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie and sorry for the unaccept, Neil, but this is a good point. As there isn't really a good general theory of infinite simple groups, I'm suddenly worried about this gap.

Comment: Kan and Thurston construct an acyclic group TG containing G functorially in G. It is defined as a semidirect product and so is not simple.  But I bet that the same circle of ideas can be tweaked to produce acyclic simple groups of arbitrarily large cardinality.

Comment: Just [verified](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348640/do-there-exist-acyclic-simple-groups-of-arbitrarily-large-cardinality/348643#348643) that this is indeed not hard.