# Does the homotopy category of spaces admit a weak generating set?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, accessible-categories

As a follow-up to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348418/do-spaces-admit-a-weak-cogenerating-set), let $\mathcal C$ be a category and $\mathcal S \subseteq \mathcal C$ a class of objects. Say that $\mathcal S$ is *weakly generating* if the functors $Hom_{\mathcal C}(S,-)$ are jointly conservative, for $S \in \mathcal S$. That is, a map $X \to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ is an isomorphism if and only if it induces a bijection $Hom_{\mathcal C}(S,X) \to Hom_{\mathcal C}(S,Y)$ for each $S \in \mathcal S$.

**Question 1:** Does the homotopy category of spaces admit a small generating set? (For example, as Simon Henry asks, do finite CW complexes work? How about the spheres?)

Of course, by Whitehead's theorem, the homotopy category of *pointed connected* spaces admits a generating set given by the spheres. But I'm not sure about unpointed spaces.

Note that the singleton set comprising the contractible space $\ast$ is a generator in the $\infty$-category of spaces, since $X \to Y$ is an equivalence if and only if $Map(\ast, X) \to Map(\ast,Y)$ is an equivalence. But passage to the the homotopy category discards the higher homotopy of the mapping spaces.

**Question 2:** More generally, if $\mathcal C$ is an accessible $\infty$-category, then does the homotopy category $h\mathcal C$ admit a small generating set? What if we assume that $\mathcal C$ is presentable?

Again, if $\mathcal C$ is $\kappa$-accessible, then the class $\mathcal C_\kappa$ of $\kappa$-compact objects forms a generating set in $\mathcal C$, but it's not clear if it forms a generating set in $h\mathcal C$. In fact, I think that Question 2 (in the "presentable" case) is equivalent to Question 1: if the answer to Question 1 is affirmative, so that $\mathcal S$ is a generating set for the homotopy category of spaces and $\mathcal T$ is a generating set for $\mathcal C$, then the set of spaces $S \ast T$ for $S \in \mathcal S, T \in \mathcal T$ forms a generating set for $h\mathcal C$. Here $\ast$ denotes [copowering](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/copower).

One result in this direction is [Rosicky's Theorem](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/TAC/volumes/14/19/14-19.pdf), which says (in model-independent language) that if $\mathcal C$ is a presentable $\infty$-category, then the canonical functor $h\mathcal C \to Ind_\kappa(h\mathcal C_\kappa)$ is essentially surjective  <strike>and full</strike>  for some $\kappa$. For my purposes, it would suffice to know that this functor is conservative for some $\kappa$.

Comment: Naive question: what the status of the class of finite CW complexes regarding question 1 ? Is it known they are not enough, or you don't know ?

Comment: @SimonHenry I don't know -- but I imagine that somebody does! If finite CW complexes don't work, it's hard to imagine that anything will! Maybe I should add that as an additional question.

Comment: By the way, Rosicky’s paper had an error invalidating the main claims, which remain open as far as I know. The Arxiv version has been updated: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506168.pdf

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ah, thanks! I was about to use that result for something!

Comment: @TimCampion Yes, it would be a very useful theorem-Neeman shows it implies the dual of a well generated triangulated satisfies Brown representability, for instance.

Comment: A counter-example to my "theorem" is in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1102.3240.pdf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This paper by Kevin Carlson and Dan Christensen says that the answer to question one is no: *No set of spaces detects isomorphisms in the homotopy category*, arXiv:[1910.04141](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.04141).

Comment: Ah, perfect! (Though rather disappointing.) Thanks!

Comment: @TimCampion it's worth pointing out that in another paper Kevin Carlson shows that there is a 2 categorical generating set. Maybe he'll chime in to say more. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.04439.pdf

Comment: @TimCampion It all comes down to the existence of noninvertible group homomorphisms which, according to groups of bounded size, appear to be conjugate to the identity. In the 2-morphisms of the homotopy 2-category we get our hands on homotopies with endpoints fixed, repairing the mod-conjugacy problem and allowing the spheres to weakly generate. The homotopy 2-category of any presentable infinity category also gets a weak generator. I find it mysterious, spaces not being an $(\infty,2)$-category, that their homotopy 2-category should be the nice thing, but so it goes.

Comment: Carlson's paper is called _On Whitehead’s theorem beyond pointed connected spaces_ (arXiv:[1802.04439](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.04439)). @Kevin that result is remarkable to me. Why tori? Is there a good conceptual reason?

Comment: @DavidRoberts There’s nothing very special about the tori here. It’s just that the family of maps $\pi_1 L^n f$, $L$ the free loop space functor, see how $f$ acts on $\pi_n$ at each base point, and can be seen in the homotopy 2-category. I find it less intuitive to work with unbased mapping spaces from spheres, but Raptis convinced me that in fact the spheres are a generator as well.